# How can I deal with a 502 error?

Tags: web-access, api, apifunction, http-functions, webtools

I am working on a program that interfaces with a web API. Mathematica runs perfectly fine for a few hours and then, after a while, will sometimes return:

> The request to URL
>   https://api.polygon.io/v2/aggs/ticker/USB/range/1/minute/2017-04-05/2017-04-06?apiKey=personalKey
>   was not successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 502.

What I find strange about this is that I can just follow the link to the website (I changed the apiKey) and have no problems. Why am I receiving this error in Mathematica, but not when I interface with the API through a web browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I got into contact with the support for the API, and the problem was resolved on their end. Apparently, it was an error in the routers' networking configuration.